# get/post request to vk api

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, xmlhttprequest

Собрался написать простой вк месседжер. Сразу возникли проблемы с обращением к апи. Искал пару дней, пока что ни один из найденных примеров не подошел. 
Вот код простой функции, которая должна была вернуть обьект с массивом друзей
[image]

В консоли получаю ошибку:
[image]

Прошу помочь с этой проблемой. Желательно с рабочим примером.

Comment: Если именно мессенджер, то есть планируется обращение к методам `messages`, то на `js` все равно не получится, т.к. этот метод работает только у standalone приложений.....ну еще через расширение браузера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание [на первый пример](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests) («Кроссдоменный запрос с использованием JSONP»):

```
var script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
script.src = "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=210700286&fields=bdate&v=5.59&callback=callbackFunc";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

function callbackFunc(result) {
    alert(result.response[0].first_name)
}
```

Многие популярные библиотеки или фреймворки (скажем, JQuery или Mithril) умеют работать с JSONP (создавая временную callback-функцию и `<script>`) автоматически.